# How to link the Test Run results (passed, failed) to the work items status change?

Tags: polarion, work-item-type

I am working on Change Management Plan, where I want the status of a work item (configuration element) to be automatically changed based on the result of the Test Run.

I know there is an already existing Polarion function LinkedWorkItemsStatusChange which does that, but only if the two types of work items are linked. The problem here is that I am unable to find a way to link my work item (configuration element) to the Test Run since the Test Run is not a work item.

Can you tell if there is a way to link a Test Run and a Work Item? so that I can link both of them and easily execute the Polarion function LinkedWorkItemsStatusChange to change the status of the work item based on the result of the Test Run.

Thanks!